# CSS - cell's top border color

Tags: css, css-tables

I faced problem with cells top border color which has `border-collapse: separate` property. I'd like have just 1px border, which have green border.

Full example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPKjRv?editors=1100 (bundled with bootstrap css).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an outline on the tr element might help, although I think you'll still see some grey at the top:

```
outline: 1px solid #7d7;
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but it creates doubled border between cells.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to remove them, without also having a class on the `tr` above the active one - sorry!